# Is there a way to insert a worksheet code in VBA, when the worksheet has been created by some outside macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, my question is as follows:

Macros.xlsm

Data.xlsx

I create additional sheets [sheet x] in Data.xlsx on the basis of running a macro in Macros.xlsm.

Once these additional sheets, are created i want a messagebox to pop out if a value in a certain cell in Sheet x is changed. Any suggestions?

One idea that i had was for my Macros file to paste event code changes to Sheet x... but even that i am not sure how that can be done.

Comment: Have a "template" copy of the sheet (with the event code) in Macros.xlsm and copy it into Data.xlsx instead of just creating a new sheet. Note that you'll have to save Data.xlsx as an xlsm then.

Comment: `Data.xlsx` is a macro free Workbook.  While you can create vba in it at runtime,  when you save, close and reopen it, that vba will be gone